# Ошибка отсутствия атрибута при запуске Telegram бота

Tags: linux, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

Код бота Telegram не запускается, выдавая данную ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/timur/Documents/Sublime/TelegramBot/bot.py", line 7, in <module>
>   @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
> AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
> [Finished in 1.8s with exit code 1]
> ```

Собственно код (`bot.py`):

```
import config
import telebot
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def answer(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: У вас какой telebot стоит?